# How to approximate $z=a^{-1/4}$ using Newtons method?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I need a function that isn't a polynomial and leads to a $f(x)$ that doesn't have a division by the iterate. The natural way of attempting this is by getting $x^4-\dfrac{1}{a}=0$ but this is using a polynomial. Is there any other way?

Comment: what's wrong with polynomials? what type of result do you expect?

Comment: @kamil09875 There is nothing wrong. The question is aimed at finding a non-polynomial function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $x^{-4}-a=0$ ?

The Newton function is then $\dfrac{5x-ax^5}{4}$. Does division by $4$ count?

(Inspired in the [division-free Newton's method for the reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division).)

Comment: Its a polynomial though

Comment: That looks like a good function!

Comment: Thanks for the function :). What sort of constraint does this function have on the initial conditions of the iterative formula?

Comment: It looks like there aren't any as compared to the polynomial version which has a division by the iterate,right?

Comment: How could I have missed the obvious one!